# $\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^2}$ is continuously differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to solve Exercise 6.5.1. from Terrence Tao's Analysis II book. It says that the function $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ defined by
$$
f(x,y):=\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^2}
$$
if $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$, and $f(0,0):=0$ is continuously differentiable, i.e., the partial derivatives are continuous in $\mathbb R^2$.

I managed to find the partial derivatives using the quotient rule:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=
\frac{y^3(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=
\frac{xy^2(3x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}.
$$
and they are clearly continuous on $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.
However, I can't seem to prove that they are continuous at $(0,0)$.

I have seen many examples to prove that a function like this is **not** continuous at $(0,0)$ (via curves, polar coordinates, etc.) but I rarely find many examples proving that a function **is** continuous at $(0,0)$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the examples you have find, it is most likely that the _degree_ of the _numerator_ is less or equal than  the degree of the denominator. You only require now to find $\partial_x f$ and $\partial_y f$ at $(0,0)$ (by limit-definition) and show that $\partial_x f$ and $\partial_y f$ are continuous functions.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that a function $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at some $(x_0,y_0)$, it is sufficient to show that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}{g(x,y)} = g(x_0,y_0).$$

However, we first need to note that your expressions for $f_x$ and $f_y$ do not give us information about $f_x(0,0)$ or $f_y(0,0)$. They only tell us about the partials away from the origin. We can compute the partials at $(0,0)$ without too much effort, once we acknowledge that we know $f(0,0)=0$.

$$f_x(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}} = \lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{\frac{(0+h)(0)}{((0+h^2)+0^2)^2}-0}{h}}=0$$

Along almost exactly the same lines, $f_y(0,0)=0$. I'll leave the details out. Now, we will be done if we can show

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{f_x(x,y)} = 0;$$
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{f_y(x,y)} = 0.$$

For a second, let's think about what that limit means. We have a similar definition as in the 1D case: For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta$ implies $\left| f_x(x,y) \right| < \epsilon$.

Now for a mathematician's favorite step: Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. We can choose $\delta < \epsilon$, which now implies

$$|f_x(x,y)| = \left|\frac{y^3(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right| < \left|\frac{y^3(y^2+x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right| = \left|\frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|=\frac{y^2|y|}{x^2+y^2} < |y|\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2} < \delta < \epsilon.$$

In the last inequality, all we've done is rearrange $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$ in a couple different ways. The case can be argued similarly for $f_y(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you! Especially for reminding that the derivatives at zero must be calculated with the limit definition. Indeed, the quotient rule is only valid when the denominator is non-zero.

Comment: You're welcome. That's a great way of viewing it. Here is an alternative that lead me to the same conclusion: To apply the quotient rule you are really doing a shortcut to the limit definition of the partial derivative, right? But when you apply that to some fixed expression such as $f(x,y)$, the limit definition "uses" the same expression for $f(x,y)$ both for $f(x+h,y)$ AND $f(x,y)$. But if a different expression crops up at the limiting point, that's trouble. So I think it's an issue with manipulating piece-wise expressions at least as much as it's about division by zero and QR.

Comment: Wait, I just realized that if $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$, that does not mean that $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}<\frac{1}{\delta^2}$. I guess I gotta work in the last inequality a bit more

Comment: Ah yes of course. See my updated argument.

Comment: Perfect! I will now write my version of the other partial derivative for posterity (in case someone finds this thread). It is based on yours :)

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and consider $\delta=\varepsilon/3$.
So, if $0<|(x,y)|<\delta$, then
$$\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\right|=
\left|\frac{xy^2(3x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|\le
\frac{|x|y^2(3x^2+3y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=
\frac{3|x|y^2(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=
\frac{3|x|y^2}{x^2+y^2}
\le
\frac{3|x|y^2+3|x|x^2}{x^2+y^2}=
\frac{3|x|(y^2+x^2)}{x^2+y^2}=
3|x|\le3|(x,y)|<3\delta=3\varepsilon/3=\varepsilon.
$$